# Can I get Summon Arvak if I choose the Dawnguard side?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I just got Dawnguard and I got excited about crossbows.

I joined the Dawnguard because I was a werewolf. Can I get Summon Arvak if I joined Dawnguard? I know about him and I have heard it is cool. I tried searching the web but I couldn't find anything.

And can I get Auriel's Bow as a member of the Dawnguard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. Being in the Dawnguard means you also have to look for Serana's Mother as you normally would, so you'll be able to find Arvak then.
As for Auriel's Bow, it's a quest item, so you'll get it with the Dawnguard as well as you would with it's counterpart, Castle Volkihar.